# Firefox/Chrome extension for setting multiple cookies at once from a string?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, cookies

For developing reasons I sometimes need to setup a cookie from a string and test it in a browser. I usually use firebug or Cookie Manager+ on firefox, but I have to set each value one at a time, **does someone knows an extension I could use to set a cookie directly from one single string?**

For example just pasting something like:

```
Cookie1=value1; Cookie2=value2; Cookie3=value3; etc=etc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Modify Header is what you might be looking for: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/